# Condition for multiple regression model

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, data-modeling, normal-distribution

Can someone explain when doing multiple regression modelling is necessary to follow normal distribution both dependent variable and all other  independent variables? or just enough dependent variable(y) follow as normal distribution..

Comment: The *regression errors* should have a normal distribution, usually the *variables* themselves do not. Consider fitting data that is on a straight line: the variables used in the regression do not follow a normal distribution, yet a straight line will fit the data.

Comment: Thanks @JamesPhillips for your support..